# Can't open thread token of NamedPipe client: "Cannot open an anonymous level security token"

Tags: c++, winapi, window, named-pipes

I am trying to impersonate a client with `SYSTEM` privileges.
I noticed that this client it trying to connect to the named pipe: `\\.\pipe\abc`.

I setup a named pipe server `\\.\pipe\abc` and wait for it to connect.
Once it was connected, it failed:

```
[+] Creating pipe server
[+] Waiting for client to connect
[+] Client connected
[+] Client impersonated!
[+] Failed to get thread token! 1347
```

The [error 1347](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-) according to Microsoft:

> ERROR_CANT_OPEN_ANONYMOUS
>
> 1347 (0x543)
>
> Cannot open an anonymous level security token.

Why did it happen? It succeeded to impersonate but then failed to open the thread.

This is my code until the failure on `OpenThreadToken`.

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SecurityAttrs = {
      sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),
      NULL,                               // assigned access token of calling process
      FALSE
  };

  DWORD openMode = PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE | WRITE_OWNER;
  DWORD pipeMode = PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT;

  std::cout << "[+] Creating pipe server\n";
  for (;;) {
      // create the named pipe
      HANDLE pipe = NULL;

      DWORD msgSize = 1024;
      pipe = CreateNamedPipeA(
          "\\\\.\\pipe\\abc",
          openMode,
          pipeMode,
          1,              // max instances
          msgSize,        // out buffer size
          msgSize,        // in buffer size
          0,              // timeout. 0 ~= 50ms
          &SecurityAttrs);

      if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
          DWORD err = GetLastError();
          std::cout << "[!] Pipe creation failed! " << err << std::endl;
          return err;
      }

      // wait for client to connect
      std::cout << "[+] Waiting for client to connect\n";
      bool connected = ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL) ? true : (
          GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);
      if (!connected)
          continue;
      std::cout << "[+] Client connected\n";

      // read from pipe
      char buf[msgSize];
      DWORD bytesread = 0;
      bool status = ReadFile(
          pipe,
          &buf,
          msgSize,
          &bytesread,
          NULL);

      // impersonate the connector
      if (!ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(pipe)) {
          DWORD err = GetLastError();
          std::cout << "[!] Impersonation failed! " << err << std::endl;
          return -1;
      }
      std::cout << "[+] Client impersonated!\n";

      HANDLE hToken = {};

      if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, false, &hToken)) {
          DWORD err = GetLastError();
          std::cout << "[!] Failed to get thread token! " << err << std::endl;
          return err;
      }
```

Comment: Do you really need `TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS`?  If you just ask for what you actually want then maybe the call will succeed.

Comment: Oh, I will try that and update. I don't think I need the whole access.

Comment: are you sure that you got 1347 but not 1346 error ? in my test is 1346 error - `STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`. this will be if your server have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` - in this case when you try impersonate higer level token - impersonation level of token is set to `SecurityIdentification` and thread with such token fail any security check with this error. if you try open any file for example.

Comment: @RbMm I doubled checked it and it is 1347. I am running with privileged account but I didn't run it as administrator so I shouldn't have the `SeImpersonatePrivilege` and I didn't see it when I checked my binary.

Comment: in this case server look like use `SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT | SECURITY_ANONYMOUS` flags in call to `CreateFileW`

Comment: @RbMm I see. I don't have control over the client so I suppose I can't do anything about that from the server side.

Comment: @RbMm I noticed that the `GetCurrentThreadToken()` doesn't return an handle, it returns the initialized number `0xfffffffffffffffe`, not sure why. This is why the `OpenThreadToken` failed.

Comment: @E235 - GetCurrentThreadToken - this is macro, not function. unrelated to problem at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on comments, in client code -

`FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;`

used if place dwFlagsAndAttributes in call of `CreateFile`

however need notice that `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL == (SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT|SECURITY_ANONYMOUS)` and `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL == SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT`

both this flags have the same binary value `0x00100000` (and `SECURITY_ANONYMOUS == 0` )

think this is problem of design of `CreateFile` api. it have less parameters, compare [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) and it try combine different parameters in single. for instance in single `dwFlagsAndAttributes` combine `FileAttributes` + `CreateOptions` + `ObjectAttributes->SecurityQualityOfService` . so parameter is "overloaded"

Answer (score 2):

According to [OpenThreadToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthreadtoken#return-value),

> If the token has the anonymous impersonation level, the token will not
> be opened and OpenThreadToken sets ERROR_CANT_OPEN_ANONYMOUS as the
> error.

And According to [Impersonation Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/impersonation-levels),

> The client of a named pipe, RPC, or DDE connection can control the
> impersonation level. For example, a named pipe client can call the
> CreateFile function to open a handle to a named pipe and specify the
> server's impersonation level.
>
> When the named pipe, RPC, or DDE connection is remote, the flags
> passed to CreateFile to set the impersonation level are ignored. In
> this case, the impersonation level of the client is determined by the
> impersonation levels enabled by the server, which is set by a flag on
> the server's account in the directory service. For example, if the
> server is enabled for delegation, the client's impersonation level
> will also be set to delegation even if the flags passed to CreateFile
> specify the identification impersonation level.

Your named pipe client do need to call the `CreateFile` function to open a handle to a named pipe and specify the server's impersonation level.

Comment: Thanks, I monitored and found that it calls:
`CreateFileW("\\.pipe\abc", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL)`
So if I understand you, it will work only if the client will call with `dwFlagsAndAttributes` that contains: `SECURITY_ANONYMOUS`. 
No way to change something on the server, right?

Comment: @E235 - no, visa versa. look like client and use `SECURITY_ANONYMOUS` if you got such token. by default `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION` used

Comment: @RbMm but the client doesn't user `SECURITY_ANONYMOUS`, it doesn't use any impersonation levels except probably the `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION` which is default and it means that the server should be able to impersonate and I do succeed to do it.

Comment: @E235 in this case you must not got error which you got

Comment: @RbMm according to this website https://csandker.io/2021/01/10/Offensive-Windows-IPC-1-NamedPipes.html#prerequisites he wrote "By default a call without explicitly specifying the SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL (as with the later example above) is made with the Impersonation Level of SecurityAnonymous." This is probably the reason why it didn't work. The client didn't specify the security context and by default it is security anonymous and not `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION` like you wrote.

Comment: @E235 - no, if server have `SeImpersonatePrivilege` and client not use `SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT` - token have `SecurityImpersonation` level. this can be easy checked in code. if server have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` and client from another session - `SecurityIdentification` will be in token. if you can say how reproduce your case - this will be more constructive

Comment: @RbMm I checked it. I run a named pipe server with "run as Administrator" and I checked that it has the `SeImpersonatePrivilege`. This is the server code: https://pastebin.com/PgwxNKiJ (expire in 2 weeks). I connected to the server with this client code: https://pastebin.com/91Xvrk5H (expire in 2 weeks). I still received the 1347 error. Notice I used `dwFlags = FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;` in the client's code. So it seems that it doesn't have the `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION`.

Comment: If you want the full project, you can see it here:
https://github.com/csandker/InterProcessCommunication-Samples/tree/master/NamedPipes/CPP-NamedPipe-Basic-Client-Server

But just notice I changed the client's code by settings it to: `dwFlags = FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;`

Comment: @E235 -of course have the binary code, always preferred over source. it more easy detect problem by debugging binary

Comment: But in the source code I gave you can also debug it with visual studio, it far more easy than binary.

Comment: @E235 - yes, but it need first compile and build :) when binary very easy debug as is

Comment: You want me to compile it for you? I can do it.

Comment: @E235 - if you can upload client and server in binary form, which exactly reproduce your error - this will be more easy for research and exactly answer what happens

Comment: @E235 - ok, i view where error - `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL == SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT == 0x00100000`. so by fact you pass `SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT | SECURITY_ANONYMOUS | SECURITY_ANONYMOUS`

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you for figuring it.